# START_STICKY android service is not running

Tags: android, service

I wish android app to run background service that will do HTTP request every minute and show notifition when server will return certain code.

I did that and I marked server as START_STICKY to keep it in memory.
But after few days I noticed service is not running.

How to debug that situation?
Android was not rebooting for 21 days according to `uptime`

I exppected that if android unloads service when low memory then it will run it again later.
It has not killed any other service like games

```
while(true){
    try{
        // queries HTTP server
    }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

What may kill service and how do I make it more stable like vibers or skypes

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to keep a single process running forever, in Android.  START_STICKY will not save it!

Have a look at the AlarmService.  You should be able to accomplish your goal by scheduling the delivery of an intent, to your app, every minute.

Be aware that this is a pretty battery-unfriendly thing to do.  People get pretty sensitive about battery use, and scheduling an HTTP request every minute is gonna kill it.